# How to group the dataarray by day and night?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataarray of time (96) and level (27) coordinates.
I want to group the array by day and night. The timezone is UTC. I should get two dataarrays, one which contains only days, e.g. day (06:00 to 18:00) and night (18:00 to 06:00).

There is a `groupby` function in xarray and pandas, but I don't think know if there are day and night attributes available there. How can it be done?

Below is my dataarray:

```
xarray.DataArray'r' time: 96 level: 27
96.67 99.58 98.07 93.94 89.31 78.26 ... 93.84 92.73 92.42 91.3 87.91
Coordinates:
time
(time)
datetime64[ns]
2021-05-14 ... 2021-05-17T23:00:00
level
(level)
float64
100.0 125.0 150.0 ... 975.0 1e+03
Attributes: (0)
```

Comment: Could you please rewrite your question? Make use of ``` for code snippets.

Comment: @Kaisar Done!! You can have a look.

Comment: Can you please use data structures format? If you have an array, use []. If you have a dataframe, post a table with the column names specified clearly. I think what you mean by datarray is a dataframe? (I haven't heard the term dataarray) If that is the case, use ```my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=[column1, column2, etc], data=[[...row1...],[...row2...],...])```. See examples here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-create-pandas-dataframe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import xarray as xr
import datetime as dt
array = xr.DataArray(
        data=np.linspace(0,30,48),
        coords={"time": pd.date_range('2021-1-1','2021-1-3',periods=48)},
        dims=["time"],
    )
array_day = array[(array.time.dt.hour>=6)&(array.time.dt.hour<=18)]
array_night = array[~((array.time.dt.hour>=6)&(array.time.dt.hour<=18))]
```

Comment: Thanks @AMi, this is the answer suitable for xarray dataarray

Comment: Hi @Imran_Say this is exactly the code I was looking for my purposes, however I would expect the `array_day` and `array_night` values to be almost equivalent, depending on when the time series starts. What is the purpose of ~ in the `array_night` , does it just filter the opposite of what the code tells it to filter?

Comment: Hi @LukeHickinbotham ~ Consider the opposite time of day, which is night time.

Answer (score 2):

The logical steps (I can give you the code if I can reproduce your data) are:

1. Contain a column base on time indicating if it is day or night.
2. Do a `groupby` on that new column.

Some example code:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'time': pd.date_range("1:00", "21:30", freq="30min"),
                   'other-var': range(42)})

def get_day_moment(hour) -> str:
    if 6 <= hour <= 18:
        return 'day'
    return 'night'
df['day-moment'] = df['time'].dt.hour.map(get_day_moment)
df.groupby('day-moment').count()
```

Comment: You can get my datafile here [relative_humidity.nc] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Abxiez_Kr5TtktkOhYcybB-0ij6rx9a4/view?usp=sharing). I open it by using xarray,  ```import xarray as xr data = xr.open_dataset('relative_humidity.nc') data['r']```

Comment: Can you please have a look?

Comment: please read the doc of [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/getting-started-guide/quick-overview.html) and of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). When that is ready and reproducible with code I am happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

***** for pandas dataframe *****
first convert dataarray to dataframe
and try following code

```
df = array.to_dataframe('TEMP')
day = df.between_time('06:00','18:00')
night = df.between_time('00:00','05:59').append(
    df.between_time('18:00','23:59')).sort_index()
```